# During the period of practising silence(mauna), bhajan /kirtan is allowed or not?

Tags: bhakti, spirituality

Suppose if someone  is practicing mauna( silence) , then  kirtan/bhajan is allowed or not ?

My thinking : Practice of mouna mean  don't produce any sound(voices) from mouth .when  we do kirtan/bhajan  we produce sound(voices) from the mouth . This breaks  the vow of silence.

I think we should not  do kirtan/bhajan   when we are practicing  silence(moana).

I'm confused that  whether my thinking is positive or negative ?

Comment: Mauna(silence) is a worship of Nirguna Brahman/Purusha while kirtan/bhajan is a worship of Saguna Brahman/Prakriti, so both are totally opposites. You can either be silent in oneness of Advaita or do bhajan in dvaita/duality, not both together. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4X6bh18lp4